# date_default_timezone_set('UTC') not working

Tags: php, configuration, timezone

This seems to be weird but I already check everything, and still a weird thing happens.

**I can't change the timezone of my php scripts**.

First things first: what I did was something like this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo '<br>';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

this seems to be working fine when I tried this on a test http://codepad.org/rpYZ0flA.

My server's timezone is set to UTC+8:00 Taipei, but when I tried the code above it's not really working. It still shows my current date_time in my server's timezone, not following the code above.

And this is the php.ini configuration of my server:

```
date/time support                    enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2012.3
Timezone Database                   internal
Default timezone                     Europe/Berlin
```

Why this is happening? Is this already a bug? Or mistake on server_setup or I just missed something in my code?

Thank you.

**NOTE:**
My environment is a Windows 7N running in VM using PHP 5.4.4

**FIX:**

I got the fix by changing manually the php.ini

Comment: what php edition you are using?

Comment: php 5.4.4, i think there is something wrong with the VM..

Comment: check example1 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: don't forget to read the comments below on the same page, seems windows need some special treatment...

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "\n";
```

here you will find the test result http://codepad.org/gc5oYnLW

Answer (score 3):

If you want only the time in seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) with timezone. Use the code below:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
time()+date("Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work without any problems.

In case of doubt, check it with this code:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Virgin');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "\n";
```

[Here is a codepad preview](http://codepad.org/w8YbgLgC) for your convenience.

The return will look like this (with updated date and time off course):

```
2017-12-11 03:09:58 AST
2017-12-11 07:09:58 UTC
```

If that fails, double-check your server configuration… starting with your `PHP.ini` file.